# Session for guests - script adds, but doesn't set session

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I want to set session for guests, and I wrote script which should do this, and it does, but only INSERT INTO table part... I don't know why script doesn't want to set session if he has all informations.

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']))
    {
        if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']))
        {
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
        }
        else
        {
            date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zagreb');

            $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $time = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
            $query = "INSERT INTO table (ip, join_date) VALUES ('$ip', '$time')";

            mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

            $query2 = "SELECT user_id, ip, join_date WHERE ip = '$ip' AND join_date = '$time'";
            $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1)
            {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                setcookie('user_id', $row['user_id'], time() + (60 * 60));
            }


            mysqli_close($dbc);
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second query `FROM` is missing. The script doesn't know, which table you mean.

And if I see it correctly, you want to get the inserted id of the last query? You then can just use the function `mysqli_insert_id($dbc)` to get the last autoincrement id.